# CodeIgniter randomize language_key or count number of lines in _lang.php file

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multilingual

Another question about CodeIgniter language class library (I'm still new in it).
Now I use the language helper which is more easy & require less code. But I have a question:

My `application/language/english/slogan_lang.php`:

```
<?php
$lang["slogan1"] = "A little social media but with more fun!";
$lang["slogan2"] = "Where face and real name is not important.";
$lang["slogan3"] = "It's a social media. Eh, it's more like a game.";
$lang["slogan4"] = "Fantastic yet fabulous life in a screen.";
$lang["slogan5"] = "Not just poke with one finger, you can duel!";
```

My currentmethod for randomize the echo:

`<?= lang('slogan'.mt_rand(1,5)) ?>`

My question is, is there some way to echo one of the slogan randomly & dinamically if later I add or remove lines in slogan_lang.php?
Or is there any way to get number of lines in my _lang.php file? Because I'm vry aware that my echo will only randomize 1-5 statically.

[image: just preview]

I hope there's good news about it!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.You can not set lang items dynamically.If you want to set items dynamically then set `config` file.Then it is possible to get and set config items dynamically.

```
$rand =  rand(1,5);//generates a number randomly
$find = "slogan".$rand;//makes your lang variable randomly
//echo $find;
<?php echo lang($find);?> //fetches the lang item
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This won't help. It would still randomize 1-5, not dynamic based on _lang.php file's number of line. So I guess there's no way and have to set the rand second parameter manually (?)